# Unable to load JSONP data from external source using jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, jsonp

I need to check if a stream is live on justin.tv. The provide a simple JSON API, where if I query

```
http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/list.json?channel=channel_name
```

it will return specific JSON info if the stream is live.

```
var url = "http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/list.json";

$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  data: { channel: "scvrush1" },
  success: function(data) { alert(data); }
});
```

It looks like the request is successful, because when I take a look at the `Network` tab in Chrome developer tools, I can see the response

[image: jsonp request]

but the callback doesn't get executed.

I'm using jQuery 1.4.2 packed with Rails 3.1.1, but I guess that's not relaly important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must specify a callback function to use JSONP. The particular parameter that justin.tv asks for is "jsonp"

See: http://apiwiki.justin.tv/mediawiki/index.php/REST_API_Documentation

This is a little involved because they don't use the standard "callback=?" that jQuery likes. So you must manually set the callback variable.

See: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/#comment-75080188

This should work:

```
var url = "http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/list.json";

$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  data: { channel: "scvrush1" },
  success: function(data) { alert(data); },
  jsonp: "jsonp"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [justin.tv REST API docs](http://apiwiki.justin.tv/mediawiki/index.php/REST_API_Documentation), the URL needs to specify the callback as `?jsonp=?` (where the second question mark stands for the callback name that jQuery generates automatically). In jQuery, set the `jsonp` parameter:

```
var url = "http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/list.json";

$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  data: { channel: "scvrush1" },
  success: function(data) { alert(data); },
  jsonp: 'jsonp'
});
```

[Here's a demo](http://phihag.de/2011/so/jquery-justin.tv.html).

Comment: It **[works](http://phihag.de/2011/so/jquery-justin.tv.accident.html)**, but using the `jsonp` parameter is cleaner. Added a link to a demo page.